# Cleaning up archives in Postgres after using systemd

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, recovery

I'm using Postgres 9.3 and I have a master database and a hot standby one that is following the master.
The operating system is CentOS 7.

I've changed the way of starting Posgres from SysV to systemd.
I've used the standard `/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.3.service`, and it's much more simplified than the old SysV script.

After the change, I've observed that it continues to work ok.  The only downside is that the archives in the hot standby are never deleted.  It is like the `archive_cleanup_command` in `recovery.conf` were ignored.

In the .service, Postgres is started in this way:

```
pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -w -t 300
```

whereas in SysV in this other way:

```
postmaster -p $PGPORT -D $PGDATA
```

I think both of them are quite equivalent.

If I change back to SysV, then archives are not accumulated any more.

Why my archives aren't cleaned up with systemd?

Comment: Try to add more logging to PotgreSQL and look at systemd logging about PostgreSQL to find anything related. Try to temporarily replace your command in `archive_cleanup_commad` by a simple shell just creating a file, to see if it is executed or not at all. It may be a permissions problem, depending on what your command does.

Comment: Good suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the PATH environment is different.

I had this line in `recovery.conf`:

```
archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/standby/archive %r'
```

And Postgres doesn't find `pg_archivecleanup` and silently ignores it.

Solution is to change the line to this:

```
archive_cleanup_command = '/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_archivecleanup /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/standby/archive %r'
```